# How can i share WP_Query between multiple functions?

Tags: wp-query

I have 2 functions that use the same `$args` for the `WP_Query` class. How can i make it so I have to define the WP_Query class only once, and share all the returns, i.e. I should be able to loop through the query in the two functions without having to define it in each one.

Example:

```php
function first_function(){
  $args = array('post_type' => 'accomodation', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'meta_query' => array('key' => 'accomodation_type', 'value' => get_query_var('accomodation_type')));
  $query = new WP_Query($args);

  while ($query->have_posts()){
   $query->the_post();

   echo '<h1>' get_the_title() '</h1>';
  }
}
add_action('load_first_function', 'first_function');

function second_function(){
  $args = array('post_type' => 'accomodation', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'meta_query' => array('key' => 'accomodation_type', 'value' => get_query_var('accomodation_type'));
  $query = new WP_Query($args);

  while ($query->have_posts()){
   $query->the_post();

   echo '<h1>' get_the_title() '</h1>';
  }
}
add_action('load_second_function', 'second_function');
```

Comment: Is the only difference the number of posts?

Comment: @TonyDjukic Hmm. I think there won't be any differences in the `$args`, I will update the question. I only would like to have to define it once, because i have multiple `meta_query` values and i don't want to have to define it each time. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: If the number of posts per page is different then they are _not_ the same. Note that you should not expect to see performance gains, WordPress holds a copy of posts in memory so that it doesn't request the same post multiple times, you would not be saving any time or resources, or avoiding database queries

Comment: @TomJNowell I have updated my question, the number of posts can be the same. Its really not about performance, i just want to keep my code DRY. I have multiple `meta_query` values, that i am getting using `get_query_var` function, i don't want to define it each time. Note that each function has its own use case, i dont want to write all the details cause it can get confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reduce code duplication, then extract the code into its own function, e.g.:

```php
function get_xyz_query_args( ) : array {
    return array('post_type' => 'accomodation', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'meta_query' => array('key' => 'accomodation_type', 'value' => get_query_var('accomodation_type')));
}
```

....

```php
$args = get_xyz_query_args();
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
```

However, there is very little performance to be gained by recycling the `WP_Query` object, and potential losses if it's done correctly. The complexity introduced would mean new bugs.

Since WP stores posts it fetches and post meta in `WP_Cache`, the second `WP_Query` only needs to fetch post IDs. On top of that, any caching plugin or object cache present can eliminate the database query completely.

So this is not worth doing if performance is your goal, there are better ways.

Comment: This is actually a good solution and works in my case, I somehow didn't think of it. Thanks!